# Publish multiple packages from subfolders

Tags: npm, package, npm-publish, .npmrc

So let's say I have a project called elements.
In this elements project I managed to do npm publish by adding .npmrc file and proper package.json to the root of the project.

What would be the best way to approach publishing if I was to introduce new components where every component is placed in a new folder and every component should be a separate package? Does then every subfolder need it's own .npmrc file with configuration? Can I somehow do a setup where I have endpoint and token in package.json and .npmrc files in root of the project but name of packages defined in subfolders?

Any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!